# how to mention current channel to another channel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'd like it so when I type `.done` it'll send the channel the command was ran in, and send it to another channel. It needs to be mentioned (Clickable) The current code I have doesn't mention the channel, but only the channel’s name. I have no idea what I'm doing, I've just been copying from the internet.

```js
if (command == "done")
return client.channels.cache.get('744836547391652000') .send(message.channel.send)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To mention a channel you need to convert it to a string using the channel's `.toString()` method. Or simply use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) like this:

```js
client.channels.cache.get("744836547391652000").send(`${message.channel}`);
```

Comment: Tysm it worked. But another problem now is that whenever I use other commands like `.close` (deletes the channel), it'll send that channel name to this channel: 744836547391652000 . I only want it to respond to `.done`

Comment: Then use an if statement like you have in your question.

Comment: Also consider marking my answer as accepted if you think that it solved the problem you presented in your question.

Comment: All the commands have an if statement, but once I added this command ( `.done`) , all other commands reply to this one as well.

Comment: You should probably post a new question about that topic and show us more of your code.